# What does form-login tag does in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application with spring security.In web-security-context.xml I found this,

```
<form-login login-page="/timeres_login"
            authentication-failure-url="/timeres_login?login_error=1"
            default-target-url="/userlogin"
```

timeres_login.jsp is the logging page, there username and password can be entered.When username and password are not matched /timeres_login?login_error=1 url is shown.And also when they are matched /userlogin url is shown.Simply this works correctly.
Now I want to change the login page to adminLogin.jsp and for that I changed timeres_login to adminLogin but still it works for timeres_login and not working for adminLogin.
Is my understanding with `<form-login />` tag incorrect? or Should I do any other thing to make this work?

Comment: Do a clean up in your ide and clean up in your server (Tomcat/Jboss/Websphere)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seams to be correct. - It is likely some deployment/refresh problem.

You should use:

```
 <form-login login-page="/adminLogin"
        authentication-failure-url="/adminLogin?login_error=1"
        default-target-url="/userlogin" />
```

*Of course you need some view-resolver hat maps `adminLogin` to `adminLogin.jsp` - but because this are typicl generic beans, so if the view-resolver mapps `timeres_login` to `timeres_login.jsp` then it will also map `adminLogin` to `adminLogin.jsp`*

For more details have a look at the Spring-Security-Reference:

- [Chapter 8.1.15](http://38.1.15%20%3Cform-login%3E)
- [3.3 Java Configuration and Form Login](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form) (it the java conter part, but it is better explained)
- [4.2.3 Form and Basic Login Options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic)